# MySql configuration for Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql-python

I am getting error when try to run

**`python manage.py migrate`**

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'someuser'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")
```

This is my database setting inside `setting.py`

```
DATABASES = { 
    'default': { 
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'read_default_file': '/config/mysql.cnf',
        },
    }
}
```

**config/mysql.cnf**

> [client]
>  database = dbname
>  user =
>   root
>  password = passwt
>  host = localhost
>   default-character-set = utf8

Comment: Some one please look into this.

Comment: You seem to use an absolute path to the config file (`/config/mysql.cnf`), but probably your actual config file is somewhere else.

Comment: /config/mysql.cnf file is in inside the project only

Comment: This is my project structure:-        <project_name>
├── <project_name>
│   ├── config
│   │   └── mysql.cnf
│   ├── dump.sql
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   └── wsgi.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── manage.py

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MySql configs can be provided in settings.py file, as like below

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
    'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
    'USER': 'DB_USER',
    'PASSWORD': 'DB_PASSWORD',
    'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
    'PORT': '3306',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'",
        'charset': 'utf8mb4',
    }
} }
```

If need to configure with external file, below may be helpful

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'read_default_file': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mysql.cnf'),
    }
} }
```

The `mysql.cnf` file should be in project dir

Comment: If i used to call mysql connect  direct from setting it will work. but i need more security so.

Comment: Ah okay. Edited my post . By this way working for me.

Comment: Thanks you it working. I removed one step config folder inside the project.